# Ckeditor Stripping Base64 Images

Tags: php, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using FMath editor plugin in My CKEditor it is inserting the equation as a base64 image and when I am saving my post It is getting properly saved inside the database, but when I am retrieving it back from the database and loading it inside the CKEditor then it is stripping the base64 image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be because of your ckeditor code is not allowing "content". Please load ckeditor as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('note', {
        allowedContent: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Also you can go throgh https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter.html to know more

Comment: setting `allowedContent` to true disables the entire filter. This can be potentially harmful. It's better to explicitly allow on specific attributes or tags.

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you use https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-extraAllowedContent and not disable the ACF. Unless you want to allow your users enter everything in the editor, you should not disable the filter.

Comment: I have already suggested it @j.swiderski. And it contains all the risks as well.

Comment: @Dhananjay Kyada you should not propose using `allowedContent:true` in the first place as this answer PROMOTES BAD PRACTICE. Instead you should have spent some time yourself with ACF and propose a solution which uses `extraAllowedContent`. The `allowedContent:true` should only be used if developer wants to allow everything to be entered inside the editor (rarely the case). In all other cases `extraAllowedContent` or `disallowedContent` should be used.

Comment: @j.swiderski. Thank you for correcting me. I will change my answer.